# Jquery get image id of next element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of images, i am trying to use Jquery to find the next image id from the current element.But i cannot seem to get the jquery to work.

```
<div class="grid" style="position: relative;">
 <div class="preview">
  <img src="1.jpg" id="175" alt="">
 </div>
</div>
<div class="grid" style="position: relative;">
     <div class="preview">
      <img src="2.jpg" id="176" alt="">
     </div>
    </div>
<div class="grid" style="position: relative;">
     <div class="preview">
      <img src="3.jpg" id="177" alt="">
     </div>
    </div>
```

JavaScript

```
var childId=6;
$( ".grid" ).click(function() {
        var image=$(this).find("img");
        var imageId=image.attr("id")
        show_image(imageId,childId);
    });

function show_image(imageId,childId){
  //need to get next image id in the group for next button , but code below is returning undefined
  var nextImageId=$(".grid .preview #" + imageId).next("img").attr("id");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `.next()` directly in this case, since images are not `siblings` to each other use,

```
var nextImageId= $("#" + imageId).closest('.grid').next(".grid").find('img').attr("id");
```

Comment: Thanks, i was struggling with this issue for a while

Answer (score 0):

Use this, it will give you the image id in 'nextImageId' variable.

```
$( ".grid" ).click(function() { 
     var nextImageId = $(this).closest('.grid').next(".grid").find('img').attr("id");   
});
```

Answer (score -1):

use next() to get the next grid selector  ,then find the img

```
 $(".grid").click(function () {
    var image = $(this).find("img");
    var imageId = image.attr("id")

   var nextImageId= $(this).next(".grid").find("img").attr("id")  // get next image id
});
```